# Django: Permanent redirect of URL with regex parameters

Tags: django, django-urls

I've been looking all over and can't find what I'm looking for.
I've found a way to redirect urls without parameters and keywords - but how to do it with parameters?

I want to redirect this:

```
(r'^andelsboligforeninger/(?P<page>[\d]*?)/$', 'cooperatives'),
```

to this:

```
(r'^liste-over-andelsboligforeninger/(?P<page>[\d]*?)/$', 'cooperatives'),
```

It should be a permanent redirect. This will be good for the SEO, and I get so many debug mails because of googlebot.

Comment: Oopss may be I have misunderstood your question. Do you want to redirect it from `htaccess` Apache or wbserver you are using??

Comment: EDIT: This is actually a comment for drewman's post.
Seems a bit overkill to install an app just for redirection? I have changed the url, which is why I want to redirect it to the new url, since the old one throws 500 error (my debug is set to false, shouldnt it throw 404 if it doesn't find the url? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've found my answer in the django docs - I didn't look hard enought after all!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/generic-views/

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
     ('^foo/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/bar/%(id)s/'}),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to do some changes in the url. Use [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#url) function and then give a name to the url. You have some issues in your url, for example you have used `?P` but did'nt give a name to the capturing group. Second `[\d]*?` there is no need for `?` because `*` means there can be a digit or not at all. So after considering all the above mentioned bugs and techniques in the end your url should look like this:

```
url(r'^liste-over-andelsboligforeninger/(?P<cooperative_id>\d*)/$', 'cooperatives', name="cooperatives")
```

Then in the view you can use [reverse url resolution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) as:

```
redirect(reverse('cooperatives', kwargs={'cooperative_id': some_id}))
```

Comment: I should say, that it's only part of my urls.py file that I posted, so I do indeed have the url() tag in it.

AFAIK, naming your urls is not necessary (but might be recommended)?

I just want to avoid creating a view function for redirecting the url. It should be possible to do it directly in the url